# How to calculate address balance with daemon RPC calls?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc

Say you are trying to program `monero-wallet-cli` for the first time.

You've got a Monero daemon running that affords you this API: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html

What set of RPC calls do you need to make to calculate the final balance of the address that you have private keys to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You've got a Monero daemon running that affords you this API

You use the `monero-wallet-cli` or `monero-wallet-rpc` to work with *wallets* (interactively or programmatically, respectively), not the *daemon* (which is for working with the blockchain/network).

> How to calculate address balance with daemon RPC calls?

In the `monero-wallet-cli` you'd use the command `balance detail`, or via the `monero-wallet-rpc`, [get_balance](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance).